# query for SUM and other columns

Tags: mysql, sql

This is my query:

```
SELECT c.remaining_budget, 
       c.future_liabilities, 
       c.used_this_month, 
       bi.full_name, 
       bi.id                                                             AS 
       item_id, 
       (SELECT Sum(amount) 
        FROM   balance_histories 
        WHERE  balance_histories.budget_item_id = 21 
               AND Date_format(payment_date, '%Y-%m-01') = '2018-01-01') AS 
       monthly_usage 
FROM   families_budget_items_calcs c 
       LEFT JOIN budget_items bi 
              ON c.budget_item_id = bi.id 
WHERE  c.family_id = 54824 
       AND bi.id IN ( 21 ) 
       AND monthly_usage <> 0
```

When I execute this query I get an error: **unknown column 'monthly_usage' in WHERE clause**.

Why? It's there!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is being caused by that the alias `monthly_usage` you defined in your select clause is not available when the `WHERE` clause gets evaluated.  One immediate workaround here would be to move the check on the `monthly_usage` to a `HAVING` clause:

```
WHERE
    c.family_id = 54824 AND
    bi.id IN ( 21 )
HAVING
    monthly_usage <> 0
```

If you don't want to do this, then you may simply repeat the subquery for monthly usage in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Why wouldn't I want to do this?

Comment: Well, only MySQL has overloaded `HAVING` to behave this way.  If you went with the `HAVING` option, and then tried to port the query to another database, e.g. SQL Server or Oracle, then it would likely not run.  But repeating the subquery in the `WHERE` clause should run everywhere.

Comment: "the alias monthly_usage you defined in your select clause is not available when the WHERE clause gets evaluated". Why?

Comment: I'm not an expert in this, but I believe it has to do with that the `WHERE` clause runs first to filter off records not relevant to the query.  This happens before the select clause assigns aliases.  It is an order of operations issue.

Comment: Noam, We are talking about something called logical query processing, this means that in your query FROM statement is evaluated and processed initially and then the rest of query.
In LQP terms queries will be processed in the following order.
{ FROM --> WHERE --> GROUP BY --> HAVING --> SELECT --> ORDER BY }
So, aliasing in the select clause is used only for more relational result, so your columns can have more suitable names.

Answer (score 1):

Tim has the correct answer (and I've upvoted it).  But your query has other issues.  It would be better written as:

```
SELECT c.remaining_budget, c.future_liabilities, c.used_this_month, 
       bi.full_name, bi.id as item_id,
       (SELECT Sum(bh.amount) 
        FROM balance_histories bh
        WHERE bh.budget_item_id = 21 AND
              payment_date >= '2018-01-01' AND
              payment_date < '2018-02-01'
       ) as monthly_usage 
FROM families_budget_items_calcs c INNER JOIN
     budget_items bi 
     ON c.budget_item_id = bi.id 
WHERE c.family_id = 54824 AND
      bi.id IN ( 21 ) 
HAVING monthly_usage <> 0 ;
```

Notes:

- Your `WHERE` clause turns the outer join to an inner join, so specifying `LEFT JOIN` is misleading.
- In a query with more than one table reference, you should qualify *all* column names (unless your joins use `USING`).
- The date comparison should not use a function such as `date_format()`.  First it is hard to follow the logic.  Second, it prevents the use of an index.

Comment: Sometime answering the question isn't enough +1.